# Set cookie value to json object value

Tags: javascript, json

http://example.com/data/test.json has a cookie called ID,it's value is a number.

the contents inside the test.json file look like this:

```
{
"autoplayBgm":false,"autoplayBgs":false,"battleback1Name":"","battleback2Name":"","bgm":{"name":"","pan":0,"pitch":100,"volume":90},"bgs":{"name":"","pan":0,"pitch":100,"volume":90},"disableDashing":false,"displayName":"","encounterList":[],"encounterStep":30,"height":13,"note":"","parallaxLoopX":false,"parallaxLoopY":false,"parallaxName":"","parallaxShow":true,"parallaxSx":0,"parallaxSy":0,"scrollType":0,"specifyBattleback":false,"tilesetId":1,"width":17,
"data":[2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,2816,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
"events":[
null,
{"id":1,"name":"EV001","note":"","pages":[{"conditions":{"actorId":1,"actorValid":false,"itemId":1,"itemValid":false,"selfSwitchCh":"A","selfSwitchValid":false,"switch1Id":1,"switch1Valid":false,"switch2Id":1,"switch2Valid":false,"variableId":1,"variableValid":false,"variableValue":0},"directionFix":false,"image":{"characterIndex":0,"characterName":"","direction":2,"pattern":0,"tileId":0},"list":[{"code":122,"indent":0,"parameters":[1,1,0,0,0]},{"code":0,"indent":0,"parameters":[]}],"moveFrequency":3,"moveRoute":{"list":[{"code":0,"parameters":[]}],"repeat":true,"skippable":false,"wait":false},"moveSpeed":3,"moveType":0,"priorityType":0,"stepAnime":false,"through":false,"trigger":0,"walkAnime":true}],"x":1,"y":1}
]
}
```

I want the value of "variableValue" to synchronize with the cookie value.
For example, if cookie value changed to 99, "VariableValue" will be 99 too.
Then if few seconds later, cookie value changed to 123, "VariableValue" will be 123 too

I am new to Json
Any help is appreciated

Comment: You mean changing the file?

Comment: The cookie value changes once in a while,  I need the VariableValue to sync with the cookie value, for example, if cookie value changed to 99, VariableValue will change to 99 too.

Comment: so, get the cookie value and change variable value. what's difficultly you are facing in implementing it?

Comment: I don't know the exact code to do that